# How to test if a page is rendered from rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I'm testing access to a page with a bunch of different types of users.  I'm tyring to see which page is rendered for each type.  I can't find the right syntax to do so.  I'm also not sure if this should be in a views file rather than controller.

```
describe "GET show as admin" do
  before(:each) do
    session[:admin_user_id] = FactoryGirl.create(:admin_user).id
  end

  it "is available to view by admin" do
    data_service = FactoryGirl.create(:published_data_service)
    get :show, {:id => data_service.to_param}
    assigns(:data_service).should eq(data_service)
    response.should render_template('show')
  end
end
```

`render_template` is returning as [].

Other note: Capybara is included in the Gemfile, and is being required in `spec_helper`

Comment: *RSpec Rails doesn't render Rails views by default*. Have you `render_views` in `spec_helper.rb`?

Comment: Capybara is not required for controller specs. You can use `render_views`, but you might also consider using a request or feature spec instead.